# Keys.onPressed stops working when i focus else but then back to original item

Tags: qt, event-handling, qml, qt5, keyboard-events

im facing something which I cant explain...
I have this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.15
import 'JavaScript.js' as JS

ApplicationWindow {

    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 480 height: 800
    title: qsTr("application")
    
    Item {
        id: keyboardHandler
        focus: true
        onFocusChanged: console.log(keyboardHandler.focus);

        Keys.onPressed: { console.log(event.text; }
    }
     
    Image {
        id: focusToKeyboardHandler
        anchors.fill: parent
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: { keyboardHandler.focus = true; }
        }
    }
        
    TextField {
        id: textfieldID
    }
}
```

and when I start the application, then all keyboard strokes properly prints into console as they should...
however if i click into the TextField, then back to image, then the keystrokes dont print anything at all :(
Why? when I click on the Image, the it properly givers me focus to keyboardHandler (proved by onFocusChanged always debugs true before i start typing... so focus on keyboardHandler is always there when needed)...

Just to be sure I have also tried to change this row to:

```
 onClicked: { keyboardHandler.focus = true; keyboardHandler.forceActiveFocus(); }
```

with no luck

UPDATE: it works on physical typing onto keyboard keys... however using the barcode scanner which is HID it works only first time i start the application, not when i change focus and then back to keyboardHandler

UPDATE2: when turning application off and on works again only for the first time (or till i rechange the focus)

any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: just tested this on windows with Qt 5.15.2 and it worked as expected!

Comment: hello, also tested again via Qt 5.15.2 too, compiling under windows works fine, but compiling for Android and testing on real android device does not work